# Can't get React 15.6.1 type definitions: "ERROR: Repository not found."

Tags: reactjs, typescript, type-definition

I'm trying to install the type definitions for React 15.6.1, but I get this error:

```
$ npm install --save @types/react
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:types/react Cloning into bare repository '/Users/blablabla/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-types-react-e0f5ee6a'...
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:types/react ERROR: Repository not found.
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:types/react fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:types/react 
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:types/react Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:types/react and the repository exists.
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install types/react
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, stat 'types/react'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 16.7.0
npm ERR! command "/Users/blablabla/.nvm/v0.10.32/bin/node" "/Users/blablabla/.nvm/v0.10.32/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "@types/react"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/blablabla
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path types/react
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/blablabla/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I think I'm following the instructions from the tutorial correctly: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html

Any ideas? I've seen this same command elsewhere on the web so I'm confused why I can't find other people reporting the same problem.

Did the "git@github.com:types/react" repository get moved?

Comment: I just tried the same thing, it works fine for me. Maybe try upgrading your npm? By the way the latest version for @types/react is 16.0.7. If you want  15.6.1, you need to specify like this `npm install --save @types/react@15.6.1`

Comment: See this [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11385), maybe some fixes work for you.

Comment: Thanks, @paibamboo. It appears I was using a super-old version of node. Upgraded that and it works fine now. Phew!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I am using `nvm` to manage node versions and somehow I had been using `0.10.48`.